# How to return the length of an subarray when a filter returns null in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the below MongoDB aggregation query.

It filters through an array in a document based on a search term (and were the object is not marked as deleted - `systemDelete_DT` ) and returns the best match. Then it sorts the results by `systemCreate_DT`.

I use it for server side pagination, the `totalCount` is used by the front end to configure the pagination.

I also return the total length of the array in `groupCount` - however where there are no results when using the search I get `null`.

How do I change my query to return the total length of the array, even when there are no results found using the `$regexMatch` filter.

Expected output when there are no search results:

```
{
  _id: '61e92302bf06b87c3e21d396',
  totalCount: 0,
  list: [],
  groupCount: 4
}
```

Here is [mongodb playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0bAwGGmPuHz)

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          _id: ObjectId("61e92302bf06b87c3e21d396"),
          
        },
        
      ],
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      groupCount: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $size: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$list",
                as: "list",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$list.systemDelete_DT",
                    null
                  ]
                },
                
              },
              
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      list: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$list",
          as: "list",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$list.systemDelete_DT",
                  null
                ]
              },
              {
                $regexMatch: {
                  input: "$$list.number",
                  regex: "X"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          
        },
        
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$list"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "list.systemCreate_DT": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "groupCount": {
        $max: "$groupCount"
      },
      "list": {
        $push: "$list"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      totalCount: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $size: "$list"
          },
          null
        ]
      },
      list: {
        $slice: [
          "$list",
          1,
          20
        ]
      },
      groupCount: 1
    },
    
  }
])
```

Comment: Do you have sample data or any mongo playground?

Comment: Hey @Gibbs - Playground added :)

Comment: Total length of the array? Regardless of the match? what is the expected o/p for the playground link when there is a match and no match(0 result)?

Comment: You do have many pipelines, it's not crystal clear what is the expected o/p? Please explain more.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @Gibbs - updated the question with expected output.

Comment: What do you mean by match? The first `$match` part?

Comment: In my DB the first $match part finds the relevant document in a collection. This bit works as expected.

Comment: Can you show me a scenario where you get null? [This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gUl7LCBHvAT) ?

Comment: Yes thats it. When the search term cannot be found. Another example https://mongoplayground.net/p/FxtHgicqcpy

Comment: I feel that this could be easily achieved without so many pipelines, I am not able to decode your query fully and match against the words in the question. Someone could help here.

Comment: Yes thats it. I was missing: preserveNullAndEmptyArrays